# The Video Play button of my Slick Slider is not working

Tags: css, video, youtube, slick.js

I was wondering if someone here knows how or why my video play button of my new slick slider isn't working at http://starter.theshopbuilders.eu.

I figured it must be a CSS-thing, I've tried a whole bunch of things but nothing seems to work.

Maybe someone here has any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iFrame has the following CSS attributes:

```
.slick-slide iframe {
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

`pointer-events` basically determines whether or not an element can be altered by the user, and in this case it's set to ignore any user interaction.

Deleting the `pointer-events:none` or setting it to `pointer-events: auto` should do the trick.

Comment: Wow Sam! Thanks a lot! :) Works perfectly.